# segmentation fault when ENTERING loop

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, segmentation-fault

I have a seg fault in C++ when entering a for loop. But I mean when ENTERING IT. Here is the code I'm running:

```
std::cout<<"forcing order"<<endl;
std::cout<<"crossoverPointNumber = "<<crossoverPointNumber<<endl;
for (long j=0; j<crossoverPointNumber; j++)
{
    std::cout<<"j = "<<j<<". ";
    offsprings[1][positionsInParent1[j]] = valuesInParent2[j];  // Forces the order
}//end for j
```

The output I get on the terminal is:

```
forcing order
crossoverPointNumber = 4
Segmentation fault
```

Can anyone explain to me what am I missing here?? it seems to be either very elementary or very complex C++ stuff...

Comment: You're most likely accessing something out of its bounds. Impossible to tell with just what you posted here. (Use a debugger, your program most likely isn't aborting on the first line of the loop but on the second.)

Comment: "*it seems to be either very elementary or very complex C++ stuff...*", more like the elementaray :) Provide some more code about the declaration/initialization of `offsprings`

Comment: but then why is the line

std::cout<<"j = "<<j<<". ";

not printing?

Comment: Also: is `offsprings[1]` intended? Do you want to access the *first* element? You'd have to write `offsprings[0]`, since C arrays are zero-based.

Comment: @user1251858 That cout line won't be printing because you aren't adding an endl. The output is buffered.

Comment: @user1251858: It may be that the stdout buffer is not fully written when the segfault occurs. using stdout as a debug measure may be misleading sometimes.

Comment: The `std::cout<<"j = "<<j<<". "` is not printing, because there is no (forced or implicit) flush happening. Add a `<< std::endl` or `<< flush` and it should appear.

Comment: Or even better, if you are adding debug output to your program, use std::cerr instead so that output is not buffered and flushed to the console immediately.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't adding an *endl* to the cout stream in your loop, so the code you've posted doesn't tell us when you are getting the segmentation fault. Until you add an endl the output stream won't be flushed.

I would strongly suspect that you are running off the end of your positionsInParent1 or valuesInParent2 arrays.

Comment: yep, you guys were right, I added _endl_ and it printed
went back, looked at the code, forgot to initialize offsprings[1].
sorry for the n00bness

Comment: @user1251858 If you learn how to use a debugger, you will go a very long way. Not only will it help you catch these bugs and fix them sooner, it'll help you understand better how your code works in general by tracing through it with the aid of debugging tools.